# Google Source external repository with Bitbucket IP Whitelisting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-repository

I have a corporate bitbucket repository where IP whitelisting is enabled.

I want to mirror this repository to Google Source but it doesn't work since i don't have Google source IP to enable that in Bitbucket portal.

Any ideas of what is the CIDR configuration to add in bitbucket?

Thank you,

Phil

Comment: Are you trying to push to Google first and have that go to Bitbucket, or push to Bitbucket and have that go to Google?

Comment: Hello Jim, I push to Bitbucket and i want to have Google Repository sync.